# React Native / React - refactoring prop before render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have passed a `guest` object from one view to the next as a property. `guest` is made up of various properties `guest.name`, `guest.age`, `guest.email`, etc.

At the beginning of the class definition for the view that will be receiving the `guest` object I'd like to refactor from `this.props.guest.name` to `guest.name` so I've setup as follows:

```
class EditGuest extends Component {
  const { guest } = this.props;
  state = {
    name: guest.name,
    email: guest.email,
    age: guest.age
  };

  render() {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
}

export default EditGuest;
```

However I am receiving an error `parsing error: unexpected token, expected '('` for the line where I refactor `const { guest } = this.props`. If I define the `guest` object within the render function it works fine, but doesn't work when defined outside of it.

What's going on here?

Comment: Shouldn't that be in a method of the class? Put it in the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write that in a constructor. Something similar to below

```
class EditGuest extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   const { guest } = props;
   this.state = {
     name: guest.name,
     email: guest.email,
     age: guest.age
   };
  }

  render() {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }
}
export default EditGuest;
```

Comment: Excellent! I'm learning something everyday!